# What is the difference between the chromatic number and the list chromatic number of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am writing my term paper on the five-color-theorem and just can't seem to get my head around the difference between the chromatic number and list chromatic number of a graph.

I am aware of the basic properties and relationships such as $\chi(G)\le\chi_l(G)$ but don't quite get the concept and uses for it.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "wrap your head around" here? Which particular questions would you like to be able to answer that you aren't already? As it is, you're just isuing an open-ended invitation to explain _everything_ about list colorings, without any guidance as to what of it you actually need.

Comment: Fair enough. I need "the difference bewteen the chromatric number and the chromatic list number". I dont see why they can be different, because (as I've read) ordinary coloring is a special case of list coloring. So I ask for a basic explanation on the term "list chromatic number".

Comment: For me, it is helpful to imagine that I play a game vs an opponent. Chromatic number: I want to color my graph, but my opponent restricts the number of colors I can use more and more. How far can he get, before I cannot find a solution anymore? List chromatic number: There is an infinite number of colors and I want to color my graph, but my opponent chooses subsets of smaller and smaller sizes for the allowed colors of each vertex (and he chooses the particular subsets as malicious as possible!). How far can he get, before I cannot find a solution anymore?

Comment: I believe the smallest example showing the difference between chromatic and list chromatic numbers is the cycle $C_6$ plus a seventh edge joining two diametrically opposite vertices; the chromatic number is $2$ but the list chromatic number is $3.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example where they can be different:

Consider the *complete bipartite graph* $K_{2,4}$:

```
  ,---A---.
 /   / \   \
B   C   D   F
 \   \ /   /
  `---E---'
```

Its chromatic number is $2$ (obviously), but we can show that its *list* chromatic number must be *more than 2* because we can find a *particular* set of color lists of length $2$ that doesn't allow a coloring:

```
 A {1,2}   B {1,3}
 E {3,4}   C {2,3}
           D {1,4}
           F {2,4}
```

No matter which colors we choose for A and E, one of B, C, D, and F will be uncolorable.

On the other hand, if we have lists of length $3$, a coloring is always possible. Just choose arbitrary colors for the two vowel nodes; then in each of the consonant nodes, at most $2$ of the colors in its list of $3$ will be excluded.

So $K_{2,4}$ has chromatic number $2$ and list chromatic number $3$.

(Adapted and condensed from a $K_{3,27}$ example with the same principle in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring)).